# Pentaho Json Input missing data

Tags: pentaho, kettle

Loading JSON from a URL does not provide the same results as reading the same JSON from a file.
When reading the JSON from a URL the result is only 1-10 rows, but when reading the file it outputs all the rows.

[image: This is the Pentaho setup]

This exact setup works perfectly when I load exactly the same JSON from a .js file.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit. ?? having trouble understanding this issue !! :(

Comment: The issue is that a whole lot of data is missing when I get the JSON through a URL.

Comment: @Rishu Is it just a weird bug in Pentaho?

Comment: do you have a data sample? without being able to reproduce the issue it's unlikely anybody can help. Just saying "maybe it's a bug" isn't very helpful and even if it is a bug, any bug report requires a reproducible case.

Comment: Are you sure the content of the .js file is exactly the same as the content from the URL? if not dump the URL content into a .js file and try again.  Also; Check encodings..

Comment: Some examples are needed - if it's a matter of a truncated object, it's worth checking whether there's a special character that messes up the enclosure of the object. Another thing you could do is use a User Defined Java Class with JSON object parsing to eliminate the possibility that it's indeed a bug in the step